# How to change label text place in collectionveiw header at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

[this is screenshot(image) of my viewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FK448.png)I'm using collectionview and placed label in header, header and label created in storyboard
I want to change label text at runtime.

I know I can do it in **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind** of collectionview but I want it in viewdidload method

my code is as below

**Controller code**

```
class DeleteViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionReusableView
        headerView.labelText.text = "dummy" // this line shows dummy
        return headerView
        
    }

   let testCollectionReusableView = TestCollectionReusableView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.register(TestCollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId")
        testCollectionReusableView.labelText.text = "Test" 
// above line Xcode 12.4 shows error - **Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value**
        
    }


}
```

**Header Class File**

```
class TestCollectionReusableView: UICollectionReusableView {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best place to do this is in your `DeleteViewController` assuming that this class holds your collection view and is a data source for it.

You can simply add a new property such as `headerText: String` which may then be user in your data source method. Whenever you change the text you should reload your collection view (or just the headers) for change to take effect.

So for instance

```
class DeleteViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet private var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    private var currentHeaderText: String = "Dummy"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        changeHeaderText(to: "Some other text")
    }

    private func changeHeaderText(to text: String) {
        currentHeaderText = text
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerId", for: indexPath) as! TestCollectionReusableView
        headerView.labelText.text = currentHeaderText
        return headerView
    }

}
```

A more optimized approach may be to detect which index paths need reloading and only reload those index paths. It would even be possible to use methods like `collectionView?.visibleSupplementaryViews(ofKind: <#T##String#>)` and loop through all visible views that correspond to your class to apply the change. But this is all up to you.

Comment: I have only one Header at Top of collectionview

Comment: @Dhiren all the same

Comment: Hi,
it works. @Matic Oblak is there any method to do same thing?

Comment: @Dhiren what do you mean by that? Do you mean having a method that changes the text without calling a reload to collection view?

Comment: no, I mean without taking "currentHeaderText" and touch viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method.

Comment: @Dhiren In viewDidLoad your reusable views do not yet even exist. So you need to forward this information one way or another. You could for instance put it in a static context and use it in reusable view directly. But that means you need to remove the "dummy" line from your data source. Mostly I would not advise you to solve your problem this way.

Comment: suppose there is button on same header, 
can I get image from photo gallery then show as image?

Comment: @Dhiren You sure could. Not on a text label though. You need to add `UIImageView` to your design as well. Then have 2 properties; one for text and one for image. When user selects an image the text should clear to `nil` or `""` and image should be set. Otherwise all the same principle exactly.

Comment: How can I use getter and setter for header view outlets?

Comment: @Dhiren Could you be a bit more specific? Any instance property can be "used" with syntax `instanceName.propertyName`. Naturally the property needs to be implemented and exposed to current context (not be private for instance) and if setter is used then the property must not be readonly. A typecasting is sometimes needed so in the end it may look like `(view as? MyView).outletProperty`.